# android when checkbox is checked show fragment

Tags: android, checkbox, fragment

I am fresh at android programming and in my simple program,

> I am trying to show fragment when CheckBox is checked and remove
>   fragment when CheckBox is not checked.

In my code, when I checked the `CheckBox`, fragment is shown and when I disable the `CheckBox` fragment is removed. However when I try to show it again I can not succeed it.

this is my part of code about checkbox

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                checkBox.setText("It is on.");
                MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                if (fragment == null) 
                {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, new MyFragment()).
                            commit();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                checkBox.setText("It is off.");

                MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                if (fragment != null) 
                {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .remove(fragment)
                        .commit();
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

is there anybody can help me?

Comment: using fragments hide and show methods solved my problem. thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot probably add it because you removed it completely, try to detatch it. By detaching it Fragment keeps its state.

try this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .detach(fragment)
                        .commit();
                    }
```

Remove means the fragment instance cannot be re-attached. You will have to add it again to the fragment transaction.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if(checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                checkBox.setText("It is on.");

                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, fragment).
                            commit();

            }

            else
            {
                checkBox.setText("It is off.");             
                if (fragment != null) 
                {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .remove(fragment)
                        .commit();
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

1)Create a layout for the fragment

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="#ff0000">
  </LinearLayout>
```

2)Create your fragment class which extends Fragment

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container,false);
    }
 }
```

3) In activity_main.xml put an empty layout with id

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/frag">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

4)In MainActivity.java, Create an object of your Fragment class then add and remove it with FragmentManager

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     CheckBox cbox;
     FragmentManager manager;
     MyFragment frag;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        manager = (FragmentManager) getFragmentManager();
        frag = new MyFragment();

        cbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked==true){
                    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag, frag).commit();
                }
                else{
                    manager.beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```